# Increment and decrement not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the "good" button +1 point and make the "wrong" button to -1 point. Now It doesn't do any of that.

```html
<script>
  var score = 0;

  function scoreplus() {
    score = score++;
  }

  function scoremin() {
    if (score > 0) {
      score = score--;
    } else {
      score = 0;
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="points">
  <p id="punten">
    <script>
      document.write(score);
    </script>
  </p>

  <button class="" id="win" onclick="scoreplus();">GOOD</button>
  <button class=" " id="lose" onclick="scoremin();">WRONG</button>
</div>
```

Do you see what I did wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In order for people to help you, they need to know what it is you're trying to do, how you expect your code to work, and exactly what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes, how verry stupid of me. sorry! I've edited.

Comment: what you mean it don't do any of that? you see 0? they don't work? you tried console.log to see what the values are? or if the functions are working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run `document.write()` only one time. The clicks **don't** affect it. Use `innerHTML` instead and run the `<script>` **after** the HTML.

`score = score++` is not a correct assignment. `score++` is enough.

```html
<div class="points">
  <p id="punten"></p>
  <button class="" id="win" onclick="scoreplus();">GOOD</button>
  <button class=" " id="lose" onclick="scoremin();">WRONG</button>
</div>

<script>
  var punten = document.getElementById("punten");
  var score = 0;

  function scoreplus() {
    score++;
    punten.innerHTML = score;
  }

  function scoremin() {
    if (score > 0) {
      score--;
    } else {
      score = 0;
    }
    punten.innerHTML = score;
  }

  punten.innerHTML = score;
</script>
```